# Multiple buttons for differents actions in the same Django form

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have a Django form where I need to include buttons to make certains actions, like fill various fields, I'm doing this with javascript scripts. The problem comes when I click that button, the form validates, like if I'm submiting the form. Are there any ways to prevent this?

Comment: I think you can use ```<form onsubmit="event.preventDefault()">```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you can easily prevent submitting the form with js.

Ex:

```
<button onclick="validate(event)"> Test </button>
```

js file:

```
const validate = (event) => {
   event.preventDefault();
   //do stuff
}
```